# Jest + WebStorm + yarn workspaces = SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: intellij-idea, jestjs, webstorm

Running `yarn test` works, but starting a test using the IntelliJ WebStorm run button fails with following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

C:\pavel\repo\projectxy\libs\ui-components-redux\src\features\forms\__tests__\duck.test.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { apiErrorsToFieldErrors, apiErrorsToGeneralErrors, prepareApiErrors } from '../duck';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the real root directory in the Jest template + observe Webstorm to fill the configuration file field.

[image]

Explanation: Webstorm estimates the working directory as the one where package.json sits, so it guesses the lib, not the main package.json (with workspaces definition). This causes the configuration file to not to be found.